# Custom higher order observable mapping

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So I have an Observable which emits an array of items.

I want to map each of the items to a custom object, but one of the object fields is again fetched async, via Observables.

This is what I have so far:

```
    const resultingObs = arrayObs
        .flatMap(x => x); // map array to a stream of items
        .mergeMap(item => asyncFetch(item.id)); // get async data from another stream
```

This works well, as it maps every item to the fetched data, what I tried to achieve, so far.

What I would like to end up with, though, is to mergeMap to a custom object, something like this:

`[{item: item, fetchedData: fetchedData}, {item: item, fetchedData: fetchedData}]`

instead of

`[fetchedData, fetchedData, fetchedData]`

So I need something like map and mergeMap in the same operator, if that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: `flatMap` and `mergeMap` are the same thing, the latter being just the new name of the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map the inner async result into an object you want:

```
.mergeMap(item => asyncFetch(item.id)
  .map(fetchedData => ({
    fetchedData,
    item
  })
);
```

Comment: Yup, I realized that just before I recieved your answer... Dumb of me. Will accept, thanks